Spring Jpa OneToOne unable to change the property name for mapping
This is spring boot JPA,
I am planning to use multiple EmploymentDetails in User class.
I notice when i change the name of property employmentDetails to employmentDetail without  s or anyname in User class then in EmploymentDetails i mapped the name, it wont work unless i use the name employmentDetails.
There is no error, its just that the column employment_details_ids is empty when i change the property name of EmploymentDetails in User class.
Working
User class

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employment_details_ids", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private EmploymentDetails employmentDetails;

EmploymentDetails Class

 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employmentDetails", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;


Mysql with value

Not Working
User class

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employment_details_ids", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private EmploymentDetails employmentDetail;

EmploymentDetails Class

 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employmentDetail", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;


Mysql without value


Are you using Lombok or manually generating getters and setters?

@ArunSudhakaran Yes, i use lombok

ok, I was assuming that you were manually generating getters and setters and while changing the property name you didn't regenerate the getters and setters, making the method name unchanged.

You can try one thing when you are changing the property name to employmentDetail try changing the column name to employment_details_id instead of employment_details_ids and see if that column is getting updated. If yes, I believe it has something to do with the naming strategy and please understand this is just to identify the cause.

@ArunSudhakaran thank you for the response, i finally found the issue when i add logs its human error :) i forgot to change also the json property name that used to Post the data thats way its empty.
